# Thread.Start is not returning in some sparse cases in my c# application

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-7, tcp

I have written a TCP server application in c#. Application listens for inbound connections

using TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient() method in main listener thread.

When a connection is received, TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient() unblocks and returns TCPClient object.

On receiving a connection, a new thread is created and started to read write data to new connection.

The new thread is started by following code.

```
while(true)
{
  TcpClient client = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient();


  if (client.Connected)
  {
    Thread t = new Thread(delegate() { readWriteData(client); });
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start(); /// Problem happens here. The thread gets stuck here and doesn't move   further
  }
 }
```

The application runs fine but in some times in Windows 7 machines, the application suddenly stops listening for tcp connections.

On analysis of thread stacks of application in this state, ( Microsoft stack explorer was used to view stacks of all threads of the application )  it is found that the main listener thread is stuck on following line of the code section shown above

```
 t.Start(); /// Problem happens here. The thread gets stuck here and doesn't move   further
```

I did lot of research and couldn't find why it is happening. This behavior is observed only in windows 7 systems.

Can anybody please help me to solve this issue.

As suggested by Rob,

I am posting here stack trace shown by windbg (sos)

```
0547eae0 7282e006 mscorwks!Thread::StartThread+0xc3, calling mscorwks!_EH_epilog3
0547eb00 727ac825 mscorwks!__SwitchToThread+0xd, calling mscorwks!__DangerousSwitchToThread
0547eb10 728b9c6f mscorwks!ThreadNative::StartInner+0x1ba, calling mscorwks!__SwitchToThread
0547eb58 727e4b04 mscorwks!SafeHandle::DisposeNative+0x3a, calling mscorwks!LazyMachStateCaptureState
0547ebc8 728b9d80 mscorwks!ThreadNative::Start+0xa6, calling mscorwks!ThreadNative::StartInner
0547ec18 728b9d01 mscorwks!ThreadNative::Start+0x1f, calling mscorwks!LazyMachStateCaptureState
0547ec74 71de6afc (MethodDesc 0x71c13048 +0x8c System.Threading.Thread.Start()), calling mscorwks!ThreadNative::Start
0547ec8c 030e2a46 (MethodDesc 0x30da408 +0x25e WindowsService.Server.startListener()), calling (MethodDesc 0x71c13048 +0 System.Threading.Thread.Start())
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that Thread.Start is not returning.  More likely your method of checking or determining that is wrong.  What makes you think that Thread.Start is not returning?

Comment: Having a thread per connection is usually not recommended; it will **not** scale. How many incoming connections do you have?

Comment: How many active clients do you have at the point that it hangs? - thread-per-client doesn't always scale very well.

Comment: Can you confirm this behaviour directly (without debugger attached, or by looking at dumps)? Try surrounding the `t.Start()` with either log statements or Console.WriteLine, before and after, writing out the thread managed id or somesuch, and just confirm you really do get stuck with a "before" message and no corresponding "after" message.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone as mentioned in post, I used microsoft stack explorer to view the stack of stuck thread. Every time when this issue occurs, it shows that the state of main listener thread is running and the thread is stuck on Thread.start

Comment: @Rob I will do that but I can't do it at once as this issue gets triggered in very rare cases when application is already running for a while.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there are about 8-10 active clients at the time of hang.

Comment: @RobLevine I surronded t.Start() with log statements and triggered the issue. As expected the microsoft stack explorer is showing the main listener stuck on t.start() and also in log the "after" message is missing in the end. hence it is confirmed that what the debugger is showing is correct.

Comment: hmm - the next step may be to capture a dump file and examine it in WinDbg/SOS - to see if you can work out where Thread.Start itself is getting stuck. That is a bit of an escalation in complexity though.

Comment: Devesh, it is incredibly unlikely that Thread.Start is hanging.  So unlikely that you should confirm by writing Console.WriteLine before and after Thread.Start.  I can guarantee you will see the before and after messages.

Comment: How does `readWriteData(client)` look?

Comment: @RobLevine I have posted the stack trace of Thread.Start as shown by windbg/sos by editing my question

Comment: I am having a very similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376945/hanging-on-thread-startinternal-when-handling-a-servicestack-request
Could you clarify which kind of handles you were closing twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured out the issue.

I did close an open handle in another thread by mistake. I was closing same handle two times in a thread by using native close method via pinvoke. It might have happened that after first close of the handle, the same handle was assigned some where internal in process. After that second close was executed but it actually closed the open handle hence that led to unexplained unsuitability in the process.

After removing that second close, the issue didn't appear again.

Answer (score 1):

Still I have not found the root cause why above mention problem is happening. However to prevent my application failing because of this situation I have implemented following workaround.

The modified code is as below.

```
count = 0;

while(true)
{
  TcpClient client = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient();


  if (client.Connected)
  {
    Thread t = new Thread(delegate() { readWriteData(client); });
    t.IsBackground = true;

    ++count;
    t.Start(); /// Problem happens here. The thread gets stuck here and doesn't move   further
    ++count;
  }
```

}

I check in another thread that if value of count hasn't changed in 5 secs and the value of count is odd number that means the listener thread is stuck on t.start(). In that case, I terminate the current listener thread and start new one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that can solve your issue:

```
    // Start ThreadProc.  Note that on a uniprocessor, the new 
    // thread does not get any processor time until the main thread 
    // is preempted or yields.  Uncomment the Thread.Sleep that 
    // follows t.Start() to see the difference.
    t.Start();
    //Thread.Sleep(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Do some work.");
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx

Another way to work arround your issue might be to use the TCPListener async:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx

Comment: It can still get pre-empted, so this wouldn't change it from *working* - it would just change how *promptly* the other thread shows

Comment: My problem is that my main thread gets stuck permanently on Thread.start. I don't think it can be solved by making any thread get preempted forcefully.

Comment: This is just extra delay.  The listener thread would soon block on the accept() call when it loops back - no need for any sleep() stuff.

Comment: In my code somewhere CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject); was called twice in succession like this CloseHandle(handle); CloseHandle(handle); It created racing codition and the scond close was closing the handle which was assigned to some internal process funtion