# Hanging on "Thread.StartInternal" when handling a ServiceStack request

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, servicestack, freeze

I have a ServiceStack (4.0.46) web service which runs fine upon launch, however after having processed a few requests **and** a non deterministic duration (generally between 30mn and 24 hours), it will eventually get stuck upon handling a request (which it receives well), with the following stack trace:

[image]

This particular function from `System.Threading.Thread` seems to hang (on the last line):

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
private void Start(ref StackCrawlMark stackMark)
{
  this.StartupSetApartmentStateInternal();
  if (this.m_Delegate != null)
    ((ThreadHelper) this.m_Delegate.Target).SetExecutionContextHelper(ExecutionContext.Capture(ref stackMark, ExecutionContext.CaptureOptions.IgnoreSyncCtx));
  this.StartInternal(CallContext.Principal, ref stackMark); //HANGS HERE
}
```

When the service runs fine, `this.StartInternal` will immediately return. It is extremely unlikely there would be a .NET framework bug here, so I am wondering what could be causing this behaviour.

The `Thread` instance is obtained from a `ThreadPool` in the following section of [`AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase.ListenerCallback()`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/433368a6a45d29ec751c09ad2f21d1b30ee73377/src/ServiceStack/AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase.cs), which also calls `Thread.Start()`:

```
  this.threadPoolManager.Peek((ThreadStart) (() =>
  {
    this.ProcessRequestContext(context);
    this.threadPoolManager.Free();
  })).Start(); //HANGS HERE
```

I tried inspecting the detailed stacks of all running threads (including framework and external library code), but do not see any sign of a deadlock or anything else that would explain why the above function would not complete. The project is hosted in a console. Using a [`AppSelfHostBase` instead of a `AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Concurrency-model) did not help.

I have been struggling with this rather low-level and hard-to-quickly-reproduce issue for weeks, and am running short of ideas to debug and hopefully fix it. Any suggestion is therefore greatly welcome!

A very similar issue here: [Thread.Start is not returning in some sparse cases in my c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920939/thread-start-is-not-returning-in-some-sparse-cases-in-my-c-sharp-application)